# TYPO3 - Inline XML with data-atttributes

Tags: xml, typo3, fluid, typo3-8.x

I search for a Solution,

i have a fluid/HTML Code in a TYPO3 Template:

```
<div id="owl-main" data-owl-carousel='{"items":2}' ">
```

and now i need in this Code a Fluid XML Output: {data.pi_flexform.items}
But it dont works:

```
<div id="owl-main" data-owl-carousel='{"items":{data.pi_flexform.items}}' ">
```

Thanks for Help!

Comment: Just guessing: “pi_flexform.items” is an array, while “2" is not. Did you try to loop over pi_flexform.items first? Could you post the some code of the structure of pi_flexform.items?

Comment: pleasy specify your expected kind of output (in combination with an example of your input (data.pi_flexform.items)).